# Not able to resolve JSObject in a java applet project

Tags: java, javascript, applet, javafx-2, jsobject

I am trying to call `JSObject.getWindow(this)` in the `init` method of `JApplet` but it is not able to resolve the symbol `getWindow`.

this problem is specifically happening with a javafx application project created through netbeans , getWindow is getting resolved if used in a java application project.

I have also included the `plugin.jar` from path `Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib`.

This is a javafx application project that I created in netbeans.

Comment: *"it is not able to resolve the symbol getWindow."*  Does that mean the same as 'returns `null`' or is it something else?  Do you have a link to where we can visit the app. (& see it fail)?  It might be helpful to also add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of code that triggers the error - it should not take more than 2 dozen lines.

Comment: may be related: I've been building with Java 8 early builds, and at least since build 72 I also get a compilation failure for applets using this method (`com.netscape.JSObject.getWindow`).

Comment: I filed [RT-30622 Not able to resolve JSObject.getWindow(this) in a java applet project](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30622) against the JavaFX project to track this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason for this is that jfxrt.lib also has a class named JSObject. This JSObject does not have getWindow function defined while plugin.jar one has. If you change the dependency order of JAR and make java to resolve JSObject to plugin.jar then java is able to call getWindow function.

Following are the links to the javadocs of both the classes.Note that jfxrt one doesn't have getWindow defined.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/java/plugin2/liveconnect/jsobject-javadoc/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm using IntelliJ and just encountered a similar issue.

What I think is happening is that jfxrt.jar and plugin.jar both have `netscape.javascript.JSObject` classes, but the two classes have different signatures. IntelliJ was adding the jars from jre/lib in alphabetical order to the classpath.

By telling IntelliJ not to add jfxrt.jar to the classpath I have been able to resolve my issue because I'm not using JavaFX.

What this points to is that JavaFX requires a different approach to using JSObject - I'm no expert (not even a beginner) at JavaFX but the following page looks useful and suggests to me that calling Javascript is done differently in JavaFX using `WebEngine.executeScript()`: https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx

Answer (score 2):

Did you `import netscape.javascript.*;`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NetBeans, you should check if you added plugin.jar to your classpath.

Comment: Are you running the applet directly from your NetBeans or are you running from a browser? Maybe there's a difference there.

Answer (score 1):

> trying to call `JSObject.getWindow(this)` in the `init` method

The `JSObject` is typically not available until `start()` is called.

Comment: Even in start it is not able to resolve, giving a compile error telling that getWindow symbol not found.It is able to recognize JSObject though. This is only happening when i am creating javafx application project in Netbeans,it is working fine with a java application project.

Answer (score 1):

@deorvatsingh Here is the problem not with the netbeans the order you added the jar's. in JavaFx application jfxar.jar is visible first in netbeans cases thats the reason you are not able to get the scope for your `JSObject.getWindow(this)`,

For executing this with netbeans and fxappication you first add the the plugin.jar then add jfxrt.jar to your appication then it will recognise.