# Can't use JSObject.getWindow() method

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to find the OS and the browser in which my applet is running, and in one applet this works with

```
JSObject win = (JSObject) JSObject.getWindow(this); 
String browser = ((String) win.eval("getUserAgent();"));
```

but in the other for the JSObject.getWindow(this); I'm getting the method getWindow is undefined...
I included the the same plugin.jar in both applets, and I have the same

```
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
```

Now I really don't know what could be wrong. I tried to refresh, close Eclipse and reopen, clean, but still the same error in one of the applets, and it runs fine in the other...

Also tried the second solution from here, still no luck...
[Compilation error in Maven/Java8 build: Cannot find symbol JSObject.getWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241600/compilation-error-in-maven-java8-build-cannot-find-symbol-jsobject-getwindow)

Comment: Are you opening both applets in the same browser?

Comment: @brso05 I get stuck with this already in Eclipse...